# Retrieve data from table with foreign key

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I was wondering how can I retrieve data from table3 with the use of 2 foreign keys. I will show you my tables first then try to explain what I am trying to do and how I am doing it.

```
Table1
ID Primary key

Table2
ID Foreign key
foodID Foreign Key

Table3
foodID Primary key
food
```

So I would first get the ID in the first table and compare it with the ID in the second table and get a foodID (note this relationship is a 1 to many, so I can have many foodIDs per ID). Then I want to output all foods by using the foodID. Heres an example of what I mean because I don't feel its too clear.

Say we have and `ID = 1` and in this we have `foodID = 1` and `foodID = 2` and lastly foodID of 1 means `food = pasta` and foodID of 2 means `food = mince meat`. So in the end I would like to output both `pasta` and `mince meat`.

Heres the code I have so far, in the example above it will only output `pasta` and not `mince meat`:

```
public function getFood($id){
        $data = $this->db->get_where('Table2', array('ID' => $id)); //Where $id is the ID in Table1
        $Result = $data->result();
        foreach($Result as $row){
            $fID = $row->foodID;
        }
        $data = $this->db->get_where('Table3', array('foodID' => $fID));
        return($data);
    }
```

Heres my view where I output the food:

```
foreach($results as $row){
            echo $row->food;
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to do a join:

```
public function getFood($id){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('Table3');
    $this->db->join('Table2', 'Table2.ID = Table3.foodID');
    $this->db->where('Table2.Id',$id);

    $result = $this->db->get();
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Ive popped that into my model but I get a syntax error `$result = $this->db->get();` on that line not too sure why though, everything else makes some sense. If possible could you give me a link to read about the `JOIN` method because I have never used it before

Comment: Here is the code ignighter reference: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html and a tutorial on joins: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-using-joins.htm

Comment: its because there was a missing semi-colon and thank you for the guide

Comment: If you want to get back an array you have to change  
`$result = $this->db->get()`  
to  
`$result = $this->db->get()->result_array()`
otherwise you will get back an object.